# Save image with my own custom image in ios

Tags: ios, image, camera, imagenamed

I want to save an image to camera roll with my own imagename in ios 5.I am using AV Foundation for accessing camera features.Please help me with possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Image to save
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName.png"];  

  // Request to save the image to camera roll
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, 
              @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Hope this helps..